# Building a form dynamically and save the data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My application is on Node.js with Express and MongoDB as the backend.

Scenario is to allow Admin users to build their own forms where other users can enter data on that form.

Initially Admin users build the form information. Once done, this is how the database document looks once added in. It has information on the field.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d41a74f97941b2ff85c5e54"),
    "fieldname" : "Site Name",
    "fieldtype" : "String",
    "fieldinputtype" : "TextBox",
    "sitecatname" : "General",
    "fieldorder" : 10,
    "__v" : 0
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d41a7e597941b2ff85c5e55"),
    "fieldname" : "Site Description",
    "fieldtype" : "String",
    "fieldinputtype" : "TextBox",
    "sitecatname" : "General",
    "fieldorder" : 20,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Based on this i am able to draw the form. See how I am generating the form field names as arrays.

```
        <form action="/adminsiteconfig" method="POST">
            <div class="container">
                <% sitecats.forEach(function(catitem) {%>
                    <h2><%= catitem.sitecatname %> - <%= catitem.sitecatorder %> </h2>
                    <div class="container">
                            <% siteadmin.forEach(function(fielditem){ 
                                if (fielditem.sitecatname == catitem.sitecatname ) { %>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                        <h6><%= fielditem.fieldname %>:</h6> 
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-6">
                                        <% if (fielditem.fieldinputtype === "Text box") { %>
                                            <input class="admstudyinput" type="text" name="site[<%= fielditem.fieldname %>]" placeholder="<%= fielditem.fieldname %>">
                                        <% } %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <% } %>
                            <% }); %>
                    </div>
                 <% });%>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark" type="submit">ADD</button>
        </form>
```

it has to save it the database through the following model.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var siteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    site_name:  String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("site", siteSchema);
```

This is my post route

```
router.post("/adminsiteconfig", middleware.isLoggedin, function(req, res){
   //create a new studycategory and save it to the database.
    site.create(req.body.site, function(err,newsite){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/adminsiteconfig");
        } else {
            console.log(newsite);
            res.redirect("/adminsiteconfig"); //redirects to GET route.
        }
    });
});
```

For regular forms I usually keep a model created and the route maps the data from the form to the database document field names. How do i do that to a form that was dynamically created?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you not just push the `req.body` of `adminsiteconfig` route? It should contain all the key value pairs

Comment: I tried change the form field names to be an array (site[field1], site[field2]), etc.  pushed as req.body.site. But it did not work. It need to have the corresponding fields in the model. If the form has more fields than I have in the model, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thank you Aritra - it worked. I had to make the schema flexible with { strict: false }

Answer (score 0):

I had to make the schema flexible and it worked:

```
var siteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Site_Name:  String
},{ strict: false });
```